# How do I make a heap queue of objects in python?

Tags: python

I want to use a heap queue (http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) on a class I made in python:

```
class Dog:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

I want to compare the dogs by age in the heap queue. How do I tell python to compare my objects by age? In other words, can I somehow write a "comparator" in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to add a `__lt__` method to your class:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.age < other.age
```

If you want to be safe, add a `__eq__` method as well and decorate your class with `functools.total_ordering` to add the other comparison operators as well.